# Searching JSON data with <input> in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to build a project just to get myself familiarise with React and redux .
I have a a data from Json (axios.get) that includes data and with that data i m building a table .

So far so good, as the data displays on the table perfectly , but i m going to put a search input on top of the page , so when user try to search for a specific country , capital , region etc that table should update. so inshort im trying to achieve [THIS](http://sean-smith.me/assets/portfolio/25-react-projects/projects/Project_3/index.html)

I have a following code so far

component

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchCountries } from '../actions';
import SearchBar from './search_bar';


class FetchCountries extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {searchValue : ''}

}

componentDidMount(){
this.props.fetchCountries();
}

renderCountries() {

const { countries } = this.props;

return _.map(countries , country =>{

return (
<tr key={country.name.official}>
<td> {country.name.official} </td>
<td> {country.capital} </td>
<td> {country.region} </td>
<td> {country.subregion} </td>
</tr>
);

});

}
```

AND this is the function i want to implement

```
handleSearchTerm(event) {
// this should return value in the table by comparing value in the table and user input

}

render() {
return(
<div>
<SearchBar onSearchTermChange= { this.handleSearchTerm }/>

<table className="table table-hover">
<thead className="thead-dark">
<tr>
<th scope="col">Countries</th>
<th scope="col">Capital</th>
<th scope="col">Region</th>
<th scope="col">SubRegion</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{this.renderCountries()}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>);

}
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
return { countries: state.countries };
}


export default connect (mapStateToProps, { fetchCountries })(FetchCountries);
```

search_bar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = { term: ''}

this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this); 

}
handleChange (term) {
this.setState({term});
this.props.onSearchTermChange(term);
}

render() {

return (<input value={this.state.term} onChange= {event => this.handleChange(event.target.value)}/>);

}
}
ras
export default SearchBar;
```

reducer.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FETCH_COUNTRIES } from '../actions';

export default function (state = {} , action) {
switch(action.type){
case FETCH_COUNTRIES:
return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, 'name.official');


default:
return state;
}
}
```

Any help will be appriciated !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 2 things.

1- Save the search term in `FetchCountries` container state

2- Use Filter in renderCountries function, to filter countries by search term

Below updated code:

**Fetch Countries Container**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchCountries  } from '../actions';
import SearchBar from './search_bar';


class FetchCountries extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {searchValue : ''}
        this.renderCountries = this.renderCountries.bind(this)
        this.handleSearchTerm = this.handleSearchTerm.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchCountries();
    }

    renderCountries() {
        const { countries } = this.props;
        var searchTerm = this.state.searchValue;
        var filteredCountries = _.filter( countries , country => {
            if(country.name.official.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1 || country.capital.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1 || country.region.indexOf(searchTerm) || country.subregion.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1 )
            {
                return country;
            }
        });

        return  _.map(filteredCountries , (country) => {
             return (
                        <tr key={country.name.official}>
                        <td> {country.name.official} </td>
                        <td> {country.capital} </td>
                        <td> {country.region} </td>
                        <td> {country.subregion} </td>
                        </tr>
                    );
         })
    }

    handleSearchTerm(term) {
        this.setState(searchValue : term);
    }

    render() {
    return(
            <div>
                <SearchBar onSearchTermChange= { this.handleSearchTerm }/>
                <table className="table table-hover">
                <thead className="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                <th scope="col">Countries</th>
                <th scope="col">Capital</th>
                <th scope="col">Region</th>
                <th scope="col">SubRegion</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.renderCountries()}
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return { countries: state.countries };
}
export default connect (mapStateToProps, { fetchCountries })(FetchCountries);
```

**SearchBar Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class SearchBar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { term: ''}
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange (term) {
        this.setState({ term });
        this.props.onSearchTermChange( term );
    }

    render() {
        return (<input value={this.state.term} onChange= {event => this.handleChange(event.target.value)}/>);
    }
}
export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time , i have updated my code and got this error `bundle.js:56389 Uncaught TypeError: countries.filter is not a function
    at FetchCountries.renderCountries (bundle.js:56389)
    at FetchCountries.render (bundle.js:56474)
    at finishClassComponent (bundle.js:42862)`

Comment: I have update the code with reducer.js as may thats the issue as its returning an object

Comment: The issue is that countries is a collection i thought its an array, i updated the code to use lodash filter function to filter the collection .. this should hopefully work

Comment: Thanks, that issue is gone now but i m getting this error `bundle.js:56389 Uncaught TypeError: country.name.indexOf is not a function
bundle.js:56389 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: country.name.indexOf is not a function`

Comment: Sorry my bad seems that name is an object that has `official` inside, updated the answer to get `name.official` not `name`

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out , but now its `bundle.js:831 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, tld, cca2, ccn3, cca3, cioc, currency, callingCode, capital, altSpellings, region, subregion, languages, translations, latlng, demonym, landlocked, borders, area}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: Yeah updated answer .. in lodash to return a new filtered array and mapped you need to filter and then map ...

Comment: Theres no errors but the search input is not updating the values in the table

Comment: The above answer code structure is how you can handle search and filtering in react ... its not fully tested as i don't have all the source code... but this is how you can do filtering in your case ... i advice that you start now debugging your code... example try to `console.log` the value of `this.state.searchValue` , make sure that handlers are called correctly after input change ... and  so on... i am sure its just a small issue that you can figure it out  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also achive  your goal by save in state only the filtered data and map it in render, and set the filter data in handleSearchTerm() in any change to get updated filered data.